# How to turn my old phone into a proper router?

Tags: router

It happens that I have an old 4G Alcatel (Android 6) phone and I want to use it as a 4G modem because fibber nor ADSL will work in my location.

I'm not seeking a simple mobile hotspot, instead I would like to know if there is an app (maybe something like VyOS or OpenWRT, although **I do know** this are proper OSs and not just apps) which allow me to [traphic-shaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) and maybe [client isolation](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/wireless-isolation).

I do not know if I could wipe the storage of my old phone and try something like [OpenWRT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.andwrt) (they have this apk in the PlayStore but has lots of negative comments) and how well this will work... But I'm open to any suggestions or if anyone can point me to a site where I can ask the questions related to install any router OS into a smartphone.

Comment: You can try [ZeroShell](https://zeroshell.org) though it's EOL now.

Comment: I don't think that you will find an alternative OS that is capable to make use of the cellular modem as it is integrated within the chipset. Common routers use USB based cellular modems.

Comment: Hi @IrfanLatif, have you tried ZeroShell in a Smartphone?

Comment: Yes I did set it up in `chroot` on an x86 Android device a few years back. But it isn't worth the hassle. You can't use the UI. Everything has to be done through commandline. And most probably you'll need to rebuild your kernel and patch/rebuild/modify many scripts and binaries in the zeroshell distro. Then take over the whole communication with modem and route it through the RIL (in Android's way), if possible and necessary. Still many features won't work. And setting up advanced features like LDAP and Kerberos is an overkill if you don't need them.

Comment: A simpler and cleaner approach is to use `ip`, `tc`, `iptables`, `hostapd`, `dnsmasq` etc. from within Android environment. These can do almost everything a simple router would do. But it depends on your definition of a "proper router".

Comment: Thanks, I would further investigate in how to open a local terminal in my device and make install some tools as `iptables` and `tc`, I think that with these 2 tools I will achieve what I want.

Comment: @Archerbob sorry, I can't, I'm not tied to change OS, but to use an app which let me do the Traffic-Shaping